# Command and response generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling coming up with a good structure for a Command -> Response generic.

My goal is to have a function accept a command from a list of commands based on a Type or Interface, and use that interface to infer the response type.

So far I've managed to correctly infer the expected `data` based on the `type` property, but I can't seem to wrap my head around inferring the return type of the generic.

Any pointers towards similar examples are very much welcome! I haven't been able to find much

Code example:
[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATAInYcA8BRANFAFSggA9gIA7JAZygGsIQB7AMymwD4oBedgbQIBdANwAoUJFgJkBcBBxdeAb1FQ1UPgGkoASwr1GrdoIBcUFestQJEM5rFX1SdHDPxEEVC5z5NHB+oAvmKBfAzMbNgioqJ65ABOLHAAxtAAyhDxAG6ZAMJMALYFcFQAkhQJSamYBFwWlgD68RDUAPxmBCExcZlV0AQtwPlFJUgAgsRklDRQGdl5hcVlFb0p8krN1GBMFNQQY2YARkxMADYQJYF1qupgcPFwBQ2uUNTA8XoA5l2xK4lrhEGwyWSAAQpNyFRaHMcvFgaNypU1pgNi1trsIKCjidzpdrpY7g8noczG8PhRvqJAt0-n0oPCoeYbmpkotRs8OkC2VQxgEWdykA0SYC3gywT8WABXCjJYA6HaTCDJSXkTC5CHTWjuGRyNUC6gcDgAClZIyoZlyAEozDYjKaQQA6ZwYB1NFpMywAek9UAAMkxPjpklAjQAJAgEAAKUGScFOpygTHirx0BR0p3ulusAAt0FAAO5MSWnJBQTbF4C6fRu2g2ZlliDASXxfQUYsJuC0EogH6s3aV8unSu8UhKlUQI31NQ2MwAcnt7Lgs-w3sI2Z0tEL8ToXaoMaTzVlpxAVZYmVr2egFFIldnztcs6ghOA9fvZinVkJjw5UGOZwuFArj6ADqSY7lAnaTJAsqeBBtB-ri+gblAFBMJWcanEw+aePg1DZkWJa-tAZJfPW1KBJaYirqUs4FFBSpyhSDbUBW1hMERiZsDY5ibOiewHL+OIAYEv4qrowC0JOvE7Px2L-pcUAAD48WiMmYnJiEicp0pIBALB6J4WZ6G8FxIEAA)

```js
type MappedData<E, T extends keyof E> = E[T];
type MappedType<E> = {
    [K in keyof E]: {
        type: K;
        data: MappedData<E, K>;
    };
}[keyof E];

interface ServerCommandInterface<T> {
     _res?: T;
}

interface TestCommandA extends ServerCommandInterface<{responseA: boolean}> {
    param_a: string;
}

interface TestCommandB extends ServerCommandInterface<{responseB: boolean}> {
    param_b: string;
}

interface Commands {
    command_a: TestCommandA;
    command_b: TestCommandB;
}

function execute<C extends MappedType<Commands>>(command: C): typeof command.data._res {
    // Logic (HTTP call or similar) that would result in _res type
    return null as any;
}

const result = execute({
    type: 'command_a',
    data: {
        param_a: 'param',
    }
});

console.log(result.responseA); // I expect this to be a boolean
```

Comment: `boolean, // Works as expected as boolean is not allowed, should be string` uh, there's no value called `boolean`, what are you doing there?  The error is saying that you are using a type where a value is expected, like writing `console.log(string)` or something.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVKM7m) what you're trying to accomplish? I removed the nonsensical `boolean` from there... note that the return type is `{responseA:boolean} | undefined` because `_res` is optional.  If this is what you're looking for I can maybe write up an answer with an explanation.  If not, please elaborate on the still-unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't formulated my question well @jcalz

Here's an updated link with my exact expectation at the bottom: https://shorturl.at/iyzN4

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I would prefer for the response not to be optional, but it's definitely a limitation I can live with!

Comment: It doesn't have to be optional, it's just because the `_res` property is optional. If you want to say "not optional" [you can do that too](https://tsplay.dev/Wolv8w).  Would you prefer that version as an answer?

Comment: I definitely prefer the NonNullable option! 
If you have a better way of accomplishing of what I'm trying to do, please go ahead. 

My only requirement is for the function to accept `{type: 'something', data: ...}` and infer the accompanying request and response properties based on that, whilst keeping the definition for both request and response data in one interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238736/discussion-between-marcin-sleziak-and-jcalz).

Comment: I know I should move to chat but I always feel like I'm going into a dark alley with a stranger when I do that.  So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBPgVW) meet your needs then?

Comment: Very much so! I've vastly overcompensated things haha

Comment: All right I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think what you're looking for is something like the following helper type:

```
interface Commands {
    command_a: {
        param: { param_a: string },
        response: { responseA: boolean }
    },
    command_b: {
        param: { param_b: string },
        response: { responseB: boolean }
    }
}
```

Here each property of `Commands` has a key corresponding to the `type` property of the value passed into `execute()`.  And the value is an object type with two properties: `param` and `response`.  The `param` property corresponds to the `data` property of the value passed into `execute()`, while the `response` property corresponds to the value returned from `execute()`.  Note that the names `param` and `response` are completely arbitrary and we could have named them anything we wanted.  There is not going to be any value of type `Commands` involved here; it's just a helper type to allow us to express the call signature of `execute()` in an easy way:

```
function execute<K extends keyof Commands>(
  command: { type: K, data: Commands[K]['param'] }
): Commands[K]['response'] {
    return null as any;
}
```

So the `execute()` function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `K`, [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be one of the keys of `Commands`.  Then the parameter to `execute()` has a `type` property of type `K`, and a `data` property of type `Commands[K]['param']`.  (We're using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type of the `K`-keyed property of `Commands` and then get the `"param"`-keyed property of that).  And the return type is `Commands[K]['response']`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const result = execute({
    type: 'command_a',
    data: {
        param_a: 'param',
    }
});
```

Here the compiler infers `"command_a"` for `K`, and so the call signature is specified as

```
/* function execute<"command_a">(command: {
    type: "command_a";
    data: {
        param_a: string;
    };
}): {
    responseA: boolean;
} */
```

And thus `result` is of type

```
/* const result: {
    responseA: boolean;
} */
```

as expected:

```
result.responseA === true // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGED2BbbCwAmAzqgN7CqWpI56ED6CAXGRVewA4IwLYumouPbIxZEIMcAHNUAXwA0bdpRhQiHTGCJR+qVes3aAgiwBGmTABso+OUrmL2NXPgL1T-e5269dQ3u5iEtIOXlT6Glo6ZHpqkdoAQmYW1ray9unpwHAArmBIECCaqFAAHlBIOdAAPADSJaXQhCQA1lAAnphwGLSuRAB8ABTOdAS6EO0c0bXyqAQIEMw9Ls0A2rUAuqsA5P7Y2xtyAJQsWCvE61vbEYZQB6zsqhA5MGCoYDmWlqgIJPjtAG5gFkaFoILEiJ9wQBeBoVKpQQbkdgTKYsbYjVyMbaOKjzRaeZRUPaiVC7Hz7XGUTJHIEAegAVKhcvlCsUyvCagAiTEMBBcoa8sYPKio6I83p8rlA9j4pbIomCCmk8SSMBSGVUWRA2QnEUqOK3EyocxWGxgHWoBl04DARnUQzg-RQwnhQ1RY2m1IW4FWm3AZ2WCAAOhuHtQ0MjqAkOTQdLpqEwLQQ7VtwCAA)